# Restkit - Anyway to setup default action when 403 response received?

Tags: ios, restkit

Using Restkit, I've setup the RKObjectManager in my AppDelegate and everything is working fine. I would like to know if there's some way to setup a default action for specific response codes.

For example, a user uses my iPhone app to login to my api and gets an auth_token back to use. If at any point, for any request, I get back I get a 403 response (like if the auth_token expires) I want to change the RootViewController to my login screen.

What would be the best way to set this up in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using RestKit 0.10 you can use the given delegate method `objectLoaderDidLoadUnexpectedResponse`.

```
- (void)objectLoaderDidLoadUnexpectedResponse:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader {
    if ([[objectLoader response] statusCode] == 403) {
        // Your action here
    }
}
```

In RestKit 0.20 you can use a response descriptor for a single code or a set of codes.

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping 
                                                                                   pathPattern:nil 
                                                                                       keyPath:@"yourKeyPath" 
                                                                                   statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:403]];
```

More status code sets in the [documentation](http://restkit.org/api/0.20.0/Classes/RKObjectManager.html).

### Update

When using your BaseViewController for handling the errors of the request made in one of the other view controllers, you can set up notifications.

*BaseViewController*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    // ...

    // Set observer for notification e.g. "requestFailedWith403Error"
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handle403Error:) name:@"requestFailedWith403Error" object:self];
}

- (void)handle403Error:(NSNotification)notification 
{
    // Code for handling the error 
}
```

*SubViewController*

```
- (void)loginToServer 
{
    // ...

    // Set authorization header
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"username" password:@"password"];

    // e.g. POST to server
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:yourObject
                                       path:@"path/toserver"
                                 parameters:nil
                                    success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                        // Handling success
                                    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                        // Handling error with notification
                                        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"requestFailedWith403Error" object:self];
    }];
}
```

Too optimize your central configuration with the handling of errors you can have another look at the example code given in the [RestKit Wiki](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#centralize-configuration-in-an-object-manager) (where the error mapping is added).

Comment: So let's say I have a BaseViewController that all my viewControllers inherit from. I'm not sure how I could use the responseDescriptor to call a method in my BaseViewController if any request made using the object manager returns a 403 response. I suppose I could check the response code in the failure block of a objectRequest and call the base method if I found a 403, but I would need to remember to do this in every request. Any better way?

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: This is probably what I'll end up using, thanks! I wish there was a way when setting up the objectManager to specify a block to run on a specific error, but oh well!

Answer (score 3):

In RestKit 0.20 you can register your `RKObjectRequestOperation`, so you can pass all requests/responses through your own success/failure blocks before anything else.

http://blog.higgsboson.tk/2013/09/03/global-request-management-with-restkit/

```
#import "RKObjectRequestOperation.h"

@interface CustomRKObjectRequestOperation : RKObjectRequestOperation

@end

@implementation CustomRKObjectRequestOperation

- (void)setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:(void ( ^ ) ( RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , RKMappingResult *mappingResult ))success failure:(void ( ^ ) ( RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error ))failure
{
    [super setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^void(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        if (success) {
            success(operation, mappingResult);
        }

    }failure:^void(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error) {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"connectionFailure" object:operation];

        if (failure) {
            failure(operation, error);
        }

    }];
} 

@end
```

Then register your subclass:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] registerRequestOperationClass:[CustomRKObjectRequestOperation class]];
```

And listen for the "connectionFailure" you are sending above:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(connectionFailedWithOperation:) name:@"connectionFailure" object:nil];
```

In the listener (e.g. your AppDelegate or a login manager):

```
- (void)connectionFailedWithOperation:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = (RKObjectRequestOperation *)notification.object;
    if (operation) {

        NSInteger statusCode = operation.HTTPRequestOperation.response.statusCode;

        switch (statusCode) {
            case 0: // No internet connection
            {
            }
                break;
            case  401: // not authenticated
            {
            }
                break;

            default:
            {
            }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```